# "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId" in .net core 3.1

Tags: sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, hierarchyid

I try to upgrade my project from .net core sdk 2.2 to .net core sdk 3.1. My model class include this "public SqlHierarchyId id". In .net core sdk 2.2, SqlHierarchyId works fine with "using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types".

```
namespace Entity
{
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public class Operators
    {

        [Key]
        public int OperatorId { get; set; }

        public SqlHierarchyId OperatorHID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But this row throw exception that "InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId" when use .net core sdk 3.1.
[image: error screen shoot]
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot?

Comment: You right, i added screenshoot in the post @NadeemTaj